# Yiic shell is not working

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii framework. I have installed Yii. I found yiic as M-DOS batch file in framework folder. When I click on it, a window appears and suddenly vanish.
I am actually looking for Yiic that is used to create web applications. If what I found is yiic then what is the matter with it, why its not opening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this video will help u
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pLAtEpWiX0&list=PLB13B786B927F8F53

Answer (score 2):

`yiic.bat` is a command line tool. So you need to open a command line window first. Then you change to the Yii directory and call the `yiic.bat` from there.

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chdos.htm) you find instructions on how to open such a command line window.